# How to disable animations for a view and all it's subviews temporarily?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-animation

I have some views with subviews, and there are animations going on. Before using shouldRasterize = YES I want to disable animations, so that all animation commands will be ignored inside that view hierarchy sub-branch.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As said by Victor, you can use the static method `+ (void)setAnimationsEnabled:(BOOL)enabled` of *UIView* to disable animations. However, this will disable animations for *all* views after you call that method. You should remember to enable animations later. As of disabling animations for a specific hierarchy of views but no others, that is not possible.

Answer (score 10):

You can use next static method in UIView:

```
+ (void)setAnimationsEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
```

See [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) for detail info

Comment: Note that that only works if set before starting the animations.  If the animations have already been started it's ineffective.

Answer (score -1):

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
                 forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
layer.content = someImageRef;// set uiview property that you dont want it animate
[CATransaction commit];
```